# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I need to delete some duplicated lines using active record query in rails 3. Yes, the table dont have a primary key or other constraint. But is not my guilty. :)
I cant just to execute some query like Delete From "TableWhatever", because one line is correct, not two, not three. So I tried to execute something like:

Domain.delete(Domain.where(domain: 123).limit(1))

And mysql give the following error:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery': DELETE FROM `domain` WHERE `domain`.`id_domain` IN (SELECT  `domain`.`id_domain` FROM `domain`  WHERE `domain`.`id_domain` = 123 LIMIT 1)

Comment: Why so complicated? Why don't you delete without a subselect? I don't know ruby but it could be like that: `Domain.delete.where(domain: 123).limit(1)`, in plain SQL: `DELETE FROM domain WHERE id_domain = 123 LIMIT 1`.

Comment: In rails will be Domain.delete.where(123).limit(1) , but dont work like you thinking. Yes in sql is simple, but a need to do this with rails.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you run a code something like

```
domains = Domain.where(:domain => 123)
domains.pop
domains.each do |domain|
    domain.destroy
end
```

Answer (score -1):

for all)  Domain.where(domain:123).destroy

for first)  Domain.where(domain:123).first.destroy

no need to limit

Comment: The Domain.where(domain:123).first.destroy, return a sql query DELETE FROM `dominio` WHERE `dominio`.`id_dominio` = 123, in other words, all lines with id_domain: 123 are deleted. I tried this too.